# Export sql file from PhpMyadmin strange characters

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported a mysql database from phpmyadmin to sql.gz file, i would like to reimport it, but i got sql errors when trying to reimport it,

```
 -- Dumping data for table `mg_address_format`
 --

 INSERT INTO `mg_address_format` (`id_country`, `format`) VALUES
 (1, 'firstname lastname\ncompany\nvat_number\naddress1\naddress2\npostcode 
 city\nCountry:name\nphone\nphone_mobile'),
 (2, 'firstname lastname\ncompany\nvat_number\naddress1\naddress2\npostcode 
 city\nCountry:name\nphone\nphone_mobile'),
 (3, 'firstname lastname\ncompany\nvat_number\naddress1\naddress2\npostcode 
 city\nCountry:name\nphone\nphone_mobile'),
 (4, 'firstname lastname\ncompany\naddress1\naddress2\ncity State:name 
 postcode\nCountry:name\nphone\nphone_mobile'),
 (5, 'firstname lastname\ncompany\nvat_number\naddress1\naddress2\npostcode 

 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
 '?' at line 101
```

Is there any solution to uncompress the file (i'm on windows)?
EDIT
When i tried to uncompresss it

```
  gunzip -d megadealo2.sql.gz
```

I got

```
gzip: megadealo2.sql.gz: not in gzip format
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need unzip it using gunzip

Answer (score 0):

The .sql.gz denotes a compressed export; you should not change its extension to .sql but uncompress it with gunzip. Alternatively when you export, do not ask for a compressed output.

Comment: When i tried to uncompresss it 

      gunzip -d megadealo2.sql.gz

I got
gzip: megadealo2.sql.gz: not in gzip format